# Is it possible to have multiple aws cdk apps in different languages?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, aws-cdk, monorepo, infrastructure-as-code

In short, I'm researching the possibility of extending a monorepo for an app written in Python, with its associated CDK setup (code & cdk.json) to include another app written in JavaScript.

I am not finding much to indicate yes/no in the AWS Docs, other stack overflow answers, or blog posts for this scenario.

My question is then, is this possible, and if so, how & what are the caveats if any?

(To answer why a second language, as it's a fair question, it's because I'm unable to find a Python package that does true encryption for XLSX files. I can only see ones like `appose-cells` which is pay for use, or `openpyxl` which states in the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html) that the data won't be encrypted. Where as the JS library `xlsx-populate` provides encryption.)

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter what language a CDK app is written in - at the end it's all cloudformation templates.